# Connect AVD with SQL Server Database Server throught JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, android-studio, jdbc, server

I'm currently trying to connect my app with a SQL Server database. There for I use JDBC.

Unfortunately I can't solve the following error message:

> com.microsft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerExceptiom: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error:"Sockets closed". ClientConnectionId: ...

I found already plenty of similar threads asking for a solution regarding this message. Some say I have to update JRE, some say I need a never Gradle and other say I should try JTDS. Anyway non of this helped me solving the issue.
But maybe I'm just stuck in my head and I'm overseeing something. Can anyone try to help me? And by the way where do you get your information, when you try to solve similar problems, because I don't think the documentation was helpful as well.

BTW. the SQL Server dos not have any SSL encryption and it uses Port 1433.

Setup:

JDBC: mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre16.jar

Gradle Version: 7.3.3

[image]

```
public class SqlHelper {
    public static void main(Context mContext){

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.190.8:1433;databaseName=Tablename;user=User;password=Password";
    //String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.190.8:1433/DB_FrommEDV1;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";

    Connection con;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        //Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 }
}
```

I use the StrictMode because otherwise I get a NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: _BTW. the SQL Server dos not have any SSL encryption and it uses Port 1433._ Every supported version of SQL Server can encrypt connections. Try adding `;encrypt=false` to your connection string because it defaults to `true` in modern JDBC drivers and you may have an unexpected upgrade lurking.

Comment: I tryed that already but it didn't help. :/